# react native - when "resetTo" route, no animation

Tags: react-native

I am using the navigator component.
I have splash scene, and after 1 second the next scene is being show.
I need the nav stack to be reset after the splash end.
When i use the resetTo method, the transition between the scenes accord without animation.
How can i do the animation?

Comment: Can you show us your code and especially where the `Navigator`/`NavigatorIOS` is implemented ?

Comment: If you want to avoid the setTimeout hack, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37219685/1216506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone seeing this thread DO NOT use setTimeout! This is really ugly and absolutely not maintainable nor scalable. There is already something built in for that.

You can use the `onDidFocus` and it works perfectly!

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.25/docs/navigator.html#ondidfocus

```
navigatorDidFocusHandler = route => {
  // call immediatelyResetRouteStack here
};
```

But be careful here, resetting the route stack triggers a `render`. So be sure to handle this correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a workaround with some code using the `onDidFocus` prop and passing an object to the `navigator.push()` to be handled with `navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack`, something like this:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.name) {
      case 'Home':
        return (<Home navigator={navigator} {...route.props} />);
      case 'User':
        return (<User navigator={navigator} {...route.props} />);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Navigator
          ref='navigator'
          initialRoute={{ name: 'Home' }}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          onDidFocus={(route) => {
            if (route.reset) {
              this.refs.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{ name: route.name }])
            }
          }}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And to do the *magic* you call the `navigator.push` like this:

```
navigator.push({ name: 'Home', reset: true })
```

It will animate to Home and reset the stack for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using *popToTop()* instead of *resetTo(route)*. That should do the animation on any screen.

Here is list of all navigator methods: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as of now there is no straight forward way to do this, so until it is merged, I am using the following as a workaround.

First *push* and then call *immediatelyResetRouteStack* with setTimeout

```
goToScene(route) {
    this.navigator.push(route);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([route]);
    }, 800);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach at all. See my response for more explanations

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where `immediatelyResetRouteStack()` was unmounting my *EventIndex* component, and remounting a new instance of it.

This was causing problems because *EventIndex* has a `setState()` call in `componentDidMount()`. Basically the previous instance of *EventIndex* was calling `setState()` on itself after it had been unmounted (or something like that).

So, if you want to avoid this problem, you can pass the route itself as an argument to `immediatelyResetRouteStack` instead of just passing the route name.

Instead of this `navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{ name: route.name }])`

You can just pass the route like this `navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([ route ])`

That way the next scene won't unmount and remount as a new instance during navigation.