# Add animation to resetTo or immediatelyResetRouteStack in React Native?

Tags: animation, reactjs, native, navigator

I've spent the better part of today looking for a solution to this.  I have a login page that I don't want users to be able to navigate back to.  To accomplish this, it's necessary to reset the route stack, removing the login page from the stack.  While this can be accomplished with Navigator's `resetTo(route)` and `immediatelyResetRouteStack(route)` methods, these both cancel out the nice transition animation.

So, I after some vigorous Googling, I am back to StackOverflow to see if I can get some help.  What I need is an animated transition between scenes, while resetting the route stack in the process.

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743773/react-native-when-resetto-route-no-animation/), and the top answer wouldn't actually work.  You don't have access the your instance of Navigator when inside the scope of the onDidFocus method, which only gets passed the route object.  This means you can't call any of Navigator's methods from within that function.

If I do `navigator.push(route)`, and then manually run `navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack(route)` using a button, it does successfully reset the stack.  This makes me think setTimeout is the solution, but that both seems like general bad practice / a cop-out.

I can't be the only one who's had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I solved it with one workaround, the answer is in this other topic, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111701/1081603